# Error installing io-console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been troubleshooting a number of gems that wouldn't update. This is the last one and I can't seem to find a solution. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
C:\Downloads\Software>gem update  
Updating installed gems  
Updating io-console  
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...  
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
ERROR:  Error installing io-console:  
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb  
checking for rb_w32_map_errno() in ruby.h... yes  
checking for sys/ioctl.h... no  
checking for rb_io_get_write_io() in ruby/io.h... yes  
checking for dup3() in unistd.h... no  
creating Makefile  

make  
generating console-i386-mingw32.def  
compiling console.c  
console.c: In function 'console_dev':  
console.c:688:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rb_cloexec_open'  
linking shared-object io/console.so  
console.o: In function `console_dev':  
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\io-console-0.4.1/console.c:688: undefined re
ference to `rb_cloexec_open'  
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\io-console-0.4.1/console.c:695: undefined re
ference to `rb_cloexec_open'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [console.so] Error 1  


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/io-consol
e-0.4.1 for inspection.  
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/io-console-0.4.1/./gem_mak
e.out  
Nothing to update
```

When I try to create a new app I get this:

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects>rails new simple_cms -d mysql  
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Co
uld not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.7
.7, json-1.5.4, minitest-4.6.1, minitest-2.5.1, rake-10.0.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-
3.12.1, rdoc-3.9.5] (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `
to_spec'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```